# Testcontainer Could not load classpath init script

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

I tried to run the Postgres test container and init schema with data at its start.
I found many examples with the method `withInitScript(String)`, but I've got the error `org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils -- Could not load classpath init script:`
maybe I didn`t include some dependencies or what. I didn't find a solution.

There are dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.10.2'
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.6.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation group: 'org.testcontainers', name: 'postgresql', version: '1.19.4'
}
```

This is testcontainer initialization:

```
    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres;

    static {

        File dump = new File("src/test/resources/my_dump.sql");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("DUMP FILE ABS PATH: " + dump.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("DUMP FILE EXISTS: " + dump.exists());

        postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("pass")
                .withExposedPorts(5432)
                .withInitScript(dump.getAbsolutePath())
                .withDatabaseName("postgres");
    }
```

There is output:

```
> Task :common:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileJava
> Task :app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:classes
> Task :app:compileTestJava
> Task :app:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:testClasses
> Task :common:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :common:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :common:jar UP-TO-DATE
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DUMP FILE ABS PATH: /home/ilys/Programming/learn/testHibernate/app/src/test/resources/my_dump.sql
DUMP FILE EXISTS: true
11:50:15.079 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.ImageNameSubstitutor -- Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
11:50:15.173 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -- Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
11:50:15.267 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -- Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
11:50:15.268 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Docker host IP address is localhost
11:50:15.276 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 24.0.7
  API Version: 1.43
  Operating System: Manjaro Linux
  Total Memory: 64031 MB
11:50:15.291 [Test worker] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
11:50:15.376 [Test worker] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 is starting: db2b087f633ba2310499f02692f762974c07ff594efbc5ae126d5eac8db9f9a4
11:50:15.629 [Test worker] INFO tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 -- Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 started in PT0.349619688S
11:50:15.632 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper -- Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
11:50:15.632 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- Checking the system...
11:50:15.632 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory -- ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
11:50:15.633 [Test worker] INFO tc.postgres:15 -- Creating container for image: postgres:15
11:50:15.677 [Test worker] INFO tc.postgres:15 -- Container postgres:15 is starting: c7d3772fddcddf6d7aaaa60e4170edf95dc609b353317de1d291a2575bd25a8c
11:50:16.558 [Test worker] INFO tc.postgres:15 -- Container postgres:15 started in PT0.925549685S
11:50:16.559 [Test worker] INFO tc.postgres:15 -- Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32797/postgres?loggerLevel=OFF)
11:50:16.560 [Test worker] WARN org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils -- Could not load classpath init script: /home/ilys/Programming/learn/testHibernate/app/src/test/resources/my_dump.sql
11:50:16.560 [Test worker] ERROR tc.postgres:15 -- Could not start container
org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$ScriptLoadException: Could not load classpath init script: /home/ilys/Programming/learn/testHibernate/app/src/test/resources/my_dump.sql. Resource not found.
```

my_dump.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.first_table
(
    id bigserial not null,
    val text not null,
    constraint pk_setting_value primary key (id)
);

INSERT INTO first_table(val) values ('1234_test');
INSERT INTO first_table(val) values ('2345_test');
INSERT INTO first_table(val) values ('3456_test');
INSERT INTO first_table(val) values ('4567_test');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to instantiate the `File` class, as the `withInitScript` method accepts a path, relative to the `src/test/resources` directory, as a parameter.
Initialize the container as shown below.

```java
postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("pass")
                .withExposedPorts(5432)
                .withInitScript("my_dump.sql")
                .withDatabaseName("postgres");
```

Comment: could I load from another path my sql file?

Comment: If you have a directory in `src/test/resources`, for example `sql`, you can call `.withInitScript("sql/my_dump.sql")`. I haven't tried it with scripts outside that directory, but the double dot (`..`) can probably be used to refer to a file in the parent directory. For example, `.withInitScript("../my_dump.sql")` if your script is located in `src/test`.

Comment: I tried with double dot it doesn't work `Could not load classpath init script: ../my_dump.sql`. Actualy I want to use source in parent resources from module.